# Tekton pipelines - secret displayed on dashboard

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

Just wanted to know if there is a way I can stop showing the secret I created on tekton dashboard. For example -

In the tekton task running this following command -

[image]

The $APIKEY is being pulled from a secret resource created.

And in the dashboard, I am seeing the API key is displayed when running the above command -

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to pass the `apikey` from a file instead for a plain value to your app? That would be easier to handle safely.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to be from a kubernetes secret.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are always, embedded as plaintext and will be, passed as plaintext.
You will see the values not only in dashboard but even if you are using the tkn cli.

Either you use a file or a env var, see examples in

file
https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/master/task/aws-cli/0.1/aws-cli.yaml

env https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/master/task/sendmail/0.1/sendmail.yaml

Comment: Thanks will have a read but for this use-case I managed to do this by using set +x and -x before and after the shell command.